# Jetpack Compose 1.0.4 Preview & Runtime Error

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

**I'm attempting to convert an existing android application to compose. Given the below dependencies, I'm getting the following error when the app starts, and in the Preview window:**

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.createUnsafe(androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner)'
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$FakeSavedStateRegistryOwner$1.<init>(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:705)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter.<init>(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:704)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:399)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:189)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:147)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:303)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:417)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:428)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:332)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:657)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:353)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:431)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:141)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:714)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$7(RenderTask.java:870)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$2.run(RenderExecutor.kt:187)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

These are my dependencies:

```
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-appcompat-theme:0.16.0"

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.1.0-beta01"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$rootProject.composeVersion"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$rootProject.composeVersion"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$rootProject.composeVersion"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'
    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:$rootProject.composeVersion"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$rootProject.composeVersion"
```

with `rootProject.composeVersion = "1.0.4"`

**I followed a lot of advice on existing questions, and have even determined it's not an issue with my Android Studio, as I've been able to create clean projects using compose just fine.**

## Update (Based on request to post Composable Code)

Even this composable code does not compile to let me preview

```
@Composable
fun TestComposable() =
    Text(text = "This is working.")

@Preview(showSystemUi = true, showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun TestComposablePreview() =
    TestComposable()
```

Comment: this `androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.1.0-beta01` should depend on compose version too, like  `androidx.compose.ui:ui:$rootProject.composeVersion`

Comment: @JüriKin try using `Preview(showSystemUi=true, showBackground=true)` instead

Comment: Maybe you should include your composable code, to get better understanding for others.

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter what Composable code it's trying to preview. I created a new file with the above update, and it still does not compile successfully.

@PhilipDukhov I updated the ui:ui to be composeVersion, however that didn't seem to work. 

.MARSK I did have that in my preview. I updated above with some test Composable Code that still won't compile to preview.

Comment: I am using 1.0.1 version for all the compose dependencies.And this works fine. Could you try that? And activity-compose is 1.3.0-alpha06. These two are only difference which I see.

Comment: Unfortunately that also didn't work.. I appreciate the suggestion though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out the solution. The issue was with the lifecycle versioning. There was code that was accidentally forcing all lifecycle dependencies to be the same value, where some modules are still using lifecycle-extensions, so Gradle was trying to force lifecycle-extensions to use 2.4.0, which obviously doesn't exist as it is deprecated.

Removing that, and with all independent lifecycle dependencies using 2.4.0, it is working correctly.

Comment: I see we have the same problem, but you should give more context on how you solved the problem.

Comment: I definitely think there's enough context here. My issue wasn't with any out of the box Android code, but rather existing legacy code in my project. The context here is I removed that legacy code, and ensured I wasn't forcing all dependencies to use the same version with the dependency group name. I was then able to specifically version any lifecycle dependency as I needed to.